# Unable to start solr in DSE(Permission denied)

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am new in `Cassandra` After Installing DSE in `CentOS`, I started DSE services successfully but I can not start Solr services.I got error while start solr, Kindly check below error log.

```
[dba@support dse]$ bin/dse cassandra -s
Tomcat: Logging to /home/dba/tomcat
[dba@support dse]$ 18:08:21,873 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[d                                                                                                                     efault] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/Datastax/dse/resources/cas                                                                                                                     sandra/conf/logback.xml]
18:08:22,484 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction -                                                                                                                      debug attribute not set
18:08:22,493 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will sca                                                                                                                     n for changes in [[/home/Datastax/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/logback.xml]] eve                                                                                                                     ry 60 seconds.
18:08:22,493 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction -                                                                                                                      Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
18:08:22,537 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.JMXConfiguratorAction                                                                                                                      - begin
18:08:22,822 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About t                                                                                                                     o instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
18:08:22,828 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming                                                                                                                      appender as [FILE]
18:08:22,941 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@7787                                                                                                                     8e70 - Will use zip compression
18:08:22,986 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA                                                                                                                      - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] fo                                                                                                                     r [encoder] property
18:08:23,037 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - A                                                                                                                     ctive log file name: /home/Datastax/log/cassandra/system.log
18:08:23,037 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - F                                                                                                                     ile property is set to [/home/Datastax/log/cassandra/system.log]
18:08:23,039 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] -                                                                                                                      openFile(/home/Datastax/log/cassandra/system.log,true) call failed. java.io.File                                                                                                                     NotFoundException: /home/Datastax/log/cassandra/system.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Datastax/log/cassandra/system.lo                                                                                                                     g (Permission denied)
        at      at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at      at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>                                                                                                                     (ResilientFileOutputStream.java:28)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:1                                                                                                                     50)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:108)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(Rolling                                                                                                                     FileAppender.java:86)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderA                                                                                                                     ction.java:96)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Inter                                                                                                                     preter.java:317)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpre                                                                                                                     ter.java:196)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpre                                                                                                                     ter.java:182)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.ja                                                                                                                     va:62)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(Gen                                                                                                                     ericConfigurator.java:149)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(Gen                                                                                                                     ericConfigurator.java:135)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(Gen                                                                                                                     ericConfigurator.java:99)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(Gen                                                                                                                     ericConfigurator.java:49)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByRes                                                                                                                     ource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(Con                                                                                                                     textInitializer.java:150)
        at      at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.jav                                                                                                                     a:85)
        at      at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder                                                                                                                     .java:55)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:142)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.j                                                                                                                     ava:121)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:                                                                                                                     332)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:284)
        at      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:305)
        at      at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.<clinit>(AbstractDs                                                                                                                     eModule.java:20)
18:08:23,933 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About t                                                                                                                                       
INFO  12:38:25  Load of settings is done.
INFO  12:38:25  CQL slow log is enabled
INFO  12:38:25  CQL system info tables are not enabled
INFO  12:38:25  Resource level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  12:38:25  Database summary stats are not enabled
INFO  12:38:25  Cluster summary stats are not enabled
INFO  12:38:25  Histogram data tables are not enabled
INFO  12:38:25  User level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  12:38:25  Spark cluster info tables are not enabled
INFO  12:38:25  Loading settings from file:/home/Datastax/dse/resources/cassandr                                                                                                                     a/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  12:38:25  Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authori                                                                                                                     zer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64;                                                                                                                      batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_e                                                                                                                     ncryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Cassandra Cluster; column_index_size_                                                                                                                     in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/home/Datastax/commitl                                                                                                                     og; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_per                                                                                                                     iod_in_ms=10000; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=                                                                                                                     32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; c                                                                                                                     ounter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_no                                                                                                                     de_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/home/Datastax/data]; disk_failure_poli                                                                                                                     cy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_                                                                                                                     ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=com.datasta                                                                                                                     x.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_thrott                                                                                                                     le_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; ind                                                                                                                     ex_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_                                                                                                                     compression=dc; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_a                                                                                                                     ddress=172.16.16.250; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads                                                                                                                     =2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_token                                                                                                                     s=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_vali                                                                                                                     dity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5                                                                                                                     000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeo                                                                                                                     ut_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=172                                                                                                                     .16.16.250; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_cache                                                                                                                     s_directory=/home/Datastax/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.c                                                                                                                     assandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=172.16.16.250,202.129.19                                                                                                                     8.236}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=fals                                                                                                                     e; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_nativ                                                                                                                     e_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_siz                                                                                                                     e_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; t                                                                                                                     rickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout                                                                                                                     _in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  12:38:25  DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is                                                                                                                      mmap
INFO  12:38:25  Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 479MB
INFO  12:38:25  Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 479MB
INFO  12:38:25  Detected search service is enabled, setting my workload to Searc                                                                                                                     h
INFO  12:38:25  Detected search service is enabled, setting my DC to Solr
INFO  12:38:25  Initialized DseDelegateSnitch with workload Search, delegating t                                                                                                                     o com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
INFO  12:38:26  Loading settings from file:/home/Datastax/dse/resources/cassandr                                                                                                                     a/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  12:38:26  Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authori                                                                                                                     zer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64;                                                                                                                      batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_e                                                                                                                     ncryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Cassandra Cluster; column_index_size_                                                                                                                     in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_directory=/home/Datastax/commitl                                                                                                                     og; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_per                                                                                                                     iod_in_ms=10000; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=                                                                                                                     32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; c                                                                                                                     ounter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_no                                                                                                                     de_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[/home/Datastax/data]; disk_failure_poli                                                                                                                     cy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_                                                                                                                     ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=com.datasta                                                                                                                     x.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_thrott                                                                                                                     le_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; ind                                                                                                                     ex_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_                                                                                                                     compression=dc; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_a                                                                                                                     ddress=172.16.16.250; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads                                                                                                                     =2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_token                                                                                                                     s=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_vali                                                                                                                     dity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5                                                                                                                     000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeo                                                                                                                     ut_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=172                                                                                                                     .16.16.250; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_cache                                                                                                                     s_directory=/home/Datastax/saved_caches; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.c                                                                                                                     assandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=172.16.16.250,202.129.19                                                                                                                     8.236}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=fals                                                                                                                     e; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_nativ                                                                                                                     e_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_siz                                                                                                                     e_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; t                                                                                                                     rickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout                                                                                                                     _in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  12:38:26  Using Solr-enabled cql queries
INFO  12:38:26  CFS operations enabled
INFO  12:38:27  UserLatencyTracking plugin using 1 async writers
INFO  12:38:27  Initializing user/object io tracker plugin
INFO  12:38:27  Initializing CQL slow query log plugin
INFO  12:38:27  Solr node health tracking is not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Solr latency snapshots are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Solr slow sub-query log is not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Solr indexing error log is not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Solr update handler metrics are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Solr request handler metrics are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Solr index statistics reporting is not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Solr cache statistics reporting is not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Initializing Solr slow query log plugin...
INFO  12:38:27  Initializing Solr document validation error log plugin...
INFO  12:38:27  CqlSystemInfo plugin using 1 async writers
INFO  12:38:27  ClusterSummaryStats plugin using 8 async writers
INFO  12:38:27  DbSummaryStats plugin using 8 async writers
INFO  12:38:27  HistogramDataTables plugin using 8 async writers
INFO  12:38:27  ResourceLatencyTracking plugin using 8 async writers
INFO  12:38:27  Setting TTL to 604800
INFO  12:38:27  Setting TTL to 604800
INFO  12:38:27  Setting TTL to 604800
INFO  12:38:27  Setting TTL to 604800
INFO  12:38:27  Setting TTL to 604800
INFO  12:38:27  DSE version: 4.7.0
INFO  12:38:27  Hadoop version: 1.0.4.15
INFO  12:38:27  Hive version: 0.12.0.7
INFO  12:38:27  Pig version: 0.10.1
INFO  12:38:27  Solr version: 4.10.3.0.6
INFO  12:38:27  Sqoop version: 1.4.5.15.1
INFO  12:38:27  Mahout version: 0.8
INFO  12:38:27  Appender version: 3.1.0
INFO  12:38:27  Spark version: 1.2.1.2
INFO  12:38:27  Shark version: 1.1.1
INFO  12:38:27  Hive metastore version: 1
INFO  12:38:27  CQL slow log is enabled
INFO  12:38:27  CQL system info tables are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Resource level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Database summary stats are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Cluster summary stats are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Histogram data tables are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  User level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Spark cluster info tables are not enabled
INFO  12:38:27  Using com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler as query h                                                                                                                     andler for native protocol queries (as requested with -Dcassandra.custom_query_h                                                                                                                     andler_class)
INFO  12:38:28  Initializing system.schema_triggers
ERROR 12:38:31  Failed managing commit log segments. Commit disk failure policy                                                                                                                      is stop; terminating thread
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Datas                                                                                                                     tax/commitlog/CommitLog-4-1432643911014.log (Permission denied)
```

Anyone point me the way to rectify this error

Comment: please format it to make it more readable.

Comment: `at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Datastax/log/cassandra/system.lo` -make sure that file exists and has the right permissions and that you are running solr with the right user...Also make sure that file name is correct

Comment: The last error looks more interesting, but you did not submit the whole log.

Comment: did you use sudo to install DSE?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a permissions issue with the parent `Datastax` directory. On startup `DSE` will attempt to create the log file (**system.log**), and will fail if permissions are not setup correctly on the parent directories. Can you provide more info about?:

> - install method (stand-alone installer or tarball)
> - DSE version